# Unity Coroutine combined delay is longer than expected with multiple WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I am starting a coroutine which iterates a loop number of times and waiting a certain time between each iteration. But complation of the loop takes way more longer than the expected. Here is the code:

```
private IEnumerator CO_AddBladesInTime(int count, Blade blade)
    {
        var _spawnPos = blade.transform.position;
        var _counter = 0;

        var _firstTime = Time.time;
        var _calculatedTime = 0f;

        Debug.Log("entered coroutine at " + _firstTime);

        while (_counter < count)
        {
            _counter++;
            // AddNewBlade(_spawnPos, blade.Level);
            var _waitTime = bladeSpawnFreq / count;
            _calculatedTime += _waitTime;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_waitTime);
        }

        var _secondTime = Time.time;
        Debug.Log("exited coroutine at " + _secondTime);
        Debug.Log($"waited {_secondTime - _firstTime}");
        Debug.Log($"expected wait time {_calculatedTime}");
    }
```

Here is the results:

[image: Log]

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html has some explanation for why the time will not be exact. The coroutine will only run once during a frame so it will be framerate dependent.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So unity can't handle running things more than once in a frame. What can I do to overcome that?

Comment: Consider carefully re-reading https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html and figure out which times you actually interested in... Basically you need to compare completion time to the "current" time (whichever one you decide - real, real-that-can-be-paused, model/scaled time), but you need to figure out which one you really want.

Comment: Please see if my title edit makes sense (as original one is way too generic) - feel free to improve (instead of rolling back) if that doesn't match what you have trouble with.

Comment: One way is with a simple yield to wait one frame, accumulate using `Time.deltaTime` and loop inside the coroutine to spend that accumulated time keeping the remainder for the next frame.

Comment: have you changed time at all, as waitforrealseconds may give different results

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned before currently your Coroutine will wait for a minimum of `count` frames.

`WaitForSeconds` basically kind of works similar to

```
for(var time = 0f; time < timeToWait; time += Time.deltaTime)
{
    yield return null;
}
```

so even if the `timeToWait` is very very small like e.g. `0.00001` it will still wait for an entire frame - which assuming a frame-rate of `60 f/s` has a length of `0.017` seconds!

Also not sure why you did use this

```
var _waitTime = bladeSpawnFreq / count;
```

I would assume `bladeSpawnFreq` already  refers to how many objects to spawn per second. Instead I would rather expect you to calculate

```
var _waitTime = 1 / bladeSpawnFreq;
```

the time in seconds between two spawns.

---

So this might be going too fancy now and there might be more straight forward solutions but what you could do is going asynchronous.

```
// Wrapper for a thread-safe counter
private class CounterWrapper
{
    private int counter;
    
    public void Add()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    }

    public bool Reset(out int value)
    {
        value = Interlocked.Exchange(ref counter, 0);
        
        return value > 0;
    }
}

private async Task ScheduleSpawns(int count, CounterWrapper counter)
{
    var millisecondsBetweenSpawns = Mathf.RoundToInt(bladeSpawnFreq * 1000);

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        counter.Add();
        await Task.Delay(millisecondsBetweenSpawns);
    }
}

private IEnumerator CO_AddBladesInTime(int count, Blade blade)
{
    var _spawnPos = blade.transform.position;

    var counter = new CounterWrapper();
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await ScheduleSpawns(count, counter));

    var _firstTime = Time.time;
    var _expectedDuration = 1 / bladeSpawnFreq * count;
    
    while(!task.IsCompleted || counter.Reset(out var toSpawn))
    {
        // each frame you pawn as many items as scheduled by the task to fulfill the spawn rate
        for(var i = 0; i < toSpawn; i++)
        {
            AddNewBlade(_spawnPos, blade.Level);
        }

        // this yields for one frame
        yield return null;
    }

    var _secondTime = Time.time;
    Debug.Log("exited coroutine at " + _secondTime);
    Debug.Log($"duration {_secondTime - _firstTime}");
    Debug.Log($"expected duration {_expectedDuration}");
}
```

So what happens here is

- You start the `ScheduleSpawns` task as an asynchronous task (-> might even be running on a different thread).
- The `Task.Delay` is happening on a milliseconds basis and way more precise than the Unity frames (as said for 60 fps one frame alone is already 17 ms long)
- You use a thread-safe counter for the scheduled spawns
- The async task more precisely increases the counter for how many items should be spawned
- The Corotuine on the Unity main thread each frame spawns all the required items while resetting the counter again

Note that still of course this might be very slightly to long in the end due to the often mentioned nature of frames being quite long ;)